# Wordpress - отобразить parent категорию как ссылку а children как текст

Tags: wordpress

Нужно сделать мини-меню.

Есть код, который отображает, имя родителя, данной страницы, нужно сделать так что бы это имя отображалось ссылкой, т.е в случае чего юзер мог кликнуть, и перейти на ветвь назад.

```
<?php if ( 0 == $post->post_parent ) {
    the_title();
} else {
    $parents = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );
    echo apply_filters( "the_title", get_the_title( end ( $parents ) ) );
}  ?>
```

Нужно что бы результат был примерно такой:

```
Имя родителя > Имя текущей страницы
```

Именно для категорий я нашел снипет в на сайте wordpress, а вот для страниц сделать подобное, оказалось не так просто. Смысл затеи в том, что бы при навигации юзер мог просто кликать, по "веткам", по которым он переходит. А не обращаться к примеру к меню, которое есть с сбоку в сайт баре и крутить скролом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

то, что вы хотите сделать может быть "Хлебные крошки", тоесть путь от главной страницы сайта на страницу, на которой вы находитесь или подстаницу. [Ссылка на статью wp-kama](https://wp-kama.ru/id_541/samyie-hlebnyie-kroshki-breabcrumbs-dlya-wordpress.html)

Comment: Спасибо, просто не знал как это называеться, но нашел на двух сайта подобные функции, и совместил по минимому. Ибо мне не во всех разделах, результатах, они нужны.

Comment: рад был вам помочь

Comment: @webstackoverload если ответ помог решить проблему - отметь его как решенный. А для хлебных крошек  есть  и готовые плаги.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить ссылку достаточно использовать get_permalink для post_parent – в данном случае код будет такой:

```
<?php
if (0 == $post->post_parent) {
    the_title();
} else {
    echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($post->post_parent).'">'.get_the_title($post->post_parent).'</a>';
    echo ' > ';
    the_title();
}
?>
```